# How to replace many if loops in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, multiple-choice

I am creating a text-based game where the user can make many different choices and they all lead to different endings or different choices in the future. I was wondering what the best way to accomplish this is because a bunch of if loops sounds like a dumb idea because with the length I'm thinking of my if loops would start getting super far out like a mountain(see Figure 1). In pseudo-code this is what I want it to be(this is the real example) but using the if statement format(which I don't want to use)(see Figure 2).

Figure 1:

```
y = 1
x = 105
if x > 0:
    if x <200:
        if x > 50:
            if x < 150:
                if x > 100:
                    if x < 110:
                       print(x)
                    else:
                        print(y+6)
                else:
                    print(y+5)
            else:
                print(y+4)
        else:
            print(y+3)
    else:
        print(y+2)
else:
    print(y+1)
```

Figure 2:

```
if player_answer = 'yes':
    print('what is big and red')
    player_answer = input
    if player_answer = 'your mom':
        print('correct, what is small and blue')
    elif player_answer = 'your dad':
        print('wrong, what is small and blue')
    else:
        print('try again')
elif player_answer = 'no':
    print('Try answering yes next time my dude')
else:
    print('leave me alone')
```

Comment: breaking parts into functions will help clean the code up and make it much easier to read and maintain

Comment: It's not a dumb idea, but look into _dictionaries_. Absolutely this structure can be simplified but it's gonna take some research.

Comment: what is the real example? example 2 right? have you looked at dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement for many options using a dict

```
options = {(100, 110) : 0, (10, 30) : 1}
func = lambda x, c: x + c
x = 100
for key, value in options.items():
    if key[0] <= x <= key[1]:
        print('The score', func(x, value))
```